# Is there any way to have a standard account not need a password in the login screen?

Tags: greeter

I want to have the login screen with a standard account not needing to input a password to login, but having a password input for the administrator account. But there seems to be no way to do this in elementary. Everyone has to enter a password at the login screen.

My son uses my laptop occasionally, and I'd like to be able let him be able to use a parentally controlled account without having to log into it every boot (which is what happens with "log in automatically" option) or for him having to memorize an unnecessary password.

Comment: Just so you know, that deleting a privileged user password will result in executing sudo without the user's permission, which opens a vulnerability in your system. Be cautious what you run. Malicious software can run without your knowledge. Friendly advice.

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal and type this:

```
sudo passwd -d <username>
```

where `<username>` is replaced with your son's username. You should do this while being logged in to your own account, because to execute this command, you need to have sudo access.

The manpage for `passwd` command (and specifically -d option) reads:

```
   -d, --delete
       Delete a user's password (make it empty). This is a quick way to disable a
       password for an account. It will set the named account passwordless.
```